# How to display data as JSON using Routes and Controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to keep routes separate from controller.

My route is:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var controller = require('../controllers/controller');

  app.route('/').get(controller.index);
};
```

And controller is:

```
exports.index = function() {
  request = new Request(
    "MYQUERY",
    function(err, rowCount) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
      }
      connection.close();
    }
  );

  request.on('row', function(columns) {
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      if (column.value === null) {
        console.log('NULL');
      } else {
        console.log(column.value);
      }
    });
  });

  connection.execSql(request);
};
```

I am able to see the result in the terminal console but I want to return it as JSON to http. I can use the following if I am using controller and routes all together:

```
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About this wiki');
})
```

Comment: The `index` function you export will take request and response arguments like the callback go `/about`. You can then use `res.send` or `res.json` with the MySQL results.

Comment: I tried this: `exports.index = function(req, res)` and ` app.route('/').get(controller.index(req, res))` but didn't help. It says undefined `res`.

Comment: No, don't do `controller.index(req, res)`, just use `controller.index` (i.e. what you had before)

Comment: TypeError: res.send is not a function

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function to `.get` (or any router request handler) takes at least two arguments: `request` and `response`. You can see this with your example:

```
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About this wiki');
})
```

You could rewrite this to make the callback a named function rather than an anonymous function:

```
const aboutHandler = function (req, res) {
  res.send('About this wiki');
});

router.get('/about', aboutHandler);
```

Your `controller.index` is the same kind of function, so it will take those two arguments. You just have to change your function to take them:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
```

This will give you access to `res`, and you can use it as you need to do send the response via `res.send` or `res.json` if you build a JSON object by accumulating the row results. You can use `request.on('end' ...` to know when the query has emitted all its results.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but do you mean `res.json(...);`?

Comment: How to pass `res` to the controller?